# dispatch_async not executing the block

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I am using `dispatch_async` to download a file in my application's `mainThread` :

```
( void ) startDownLoading
{
   NSLog(@"Inside start downloading") ;
   dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
   {
      //Code do download my file
   } ) ;
}
```

The "Inside start downloading" log is printed. I put some break points and found out that the whole `dispatch_async` block is being skipped.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: you checked the async loop without any code (as you shown above) or with some code?

Comment: If you want to update UI then use mainThread otherwise just run your code on globalThread

Comment: @R.Mohan : I did have some code.

Comment: @himanth : I need to update UI. Precisely why I have used mainThread.

Comment: your dispatch_async code looks fine @Anand check the code you used inside the block, or show what you tried inside the block.

Comment: Maybe you have some long-running block on the main queue?  Being a serial queue, it can only run one block at once.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is just a little. Put a breakpoint inside the mainqueue block. This is because is there is any dispatch statement than breakpoints outside the block always skip or seems likes this but it doesn't. The block will get called.

Check it.